# How to find that there is duplicate data in array of dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have array of dictionary. If duplicate data is present in the array of dictionary then a flag to be raised with the element name which is duplicate.

The array of dictionary is below:

```
[[project_code: 1, lob: lob_1], [project_code: 1, lob: lob_1], [project_code: 2, lob: lob_1], [project_code: 3, lob: lob_1]]
```

Here we need to loop through and find if same project_code and lob is same, then it would return which all project_code which are duplicate.

Duplicate data means the pair of project_code and lob value should be same.

In the above array, if we go through then it should return project_code : 1

If anyone can write a code in Swift ..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This requires a custom code, one which you can very easily write yourself. Loop through the array and compare it to every other dictionary by comparing their pair and raise flag. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
var dic1 = ["project_code":1, "lob": "lob_1"]
var dic2 = ["project_code":1, "lob": "lob_1"]
var dic3 = ["project_code":2, "lob": "lob_1"]
var dic4 = ["project_code":3, "lob": "lob_1"]

var hasDuplicates = NSArray(objects: dic1,dic2,dic3,dic4)

var duplicates    = NSMutableArray()
var noDuplicates  = NSMutableArray()

for dics in hasDuplicates{

    if noDuplicates.containsObject(dics){

        if !duplicates.containsObject(dics){
            duplicates.addObject(dics)
        }
    }
    else{
        noDuplicates.addObject(dics)
    }
}

println(duplicates)
println(noDuplicates)

//to find the duplicate items key
for dics in duplicates{
    println(dics["project_code"])
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me a code which will only check the project_code and not the lob. The scenario remains same. If duplicate project_code is present irrespective of any lob... it should list all the duplicate project_Code.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**By using `extension`:**

```
extension Array {
    var isContainedDuplicateData: Bool {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < self.count; ++i){
            for (var j = i+1 ; j < self.count; ++j){

                let p = self[i] as? NSDictionary
                let q = self[j] as? NSDictionary

                if (p  == q ){
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

var duplicateData: AnyObject {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < self.count; ++i){
        for (var j = i+1 ; j < self.count; ++j){

            let p = self[i] as? NSDictionary
            let q = self[j] as? NSDictionary

            if (p  == q ){
                return p!
            }
        }
    }
    return  NSNull()
}
```

Then write the following code:

```
var arr: Array = [["a" : "b"], ["b": "c"],["a": "b"],"s"]
var status = arr.isContainedDuplicateData
var duplicatedata = arr.duplicateData
```

The result is:

```
status = false
duplicatedata = ["a": "b"]
```